# How do you GET a Project's image in BIM 360 using Postman?

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am able to create or update an existing Project's image on BIM 360 using Postman but is there any way to get `GET` the information regarding it? Using the `GET` method, there is no information regarding images as shown below.

**URL:**
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/{{Account_Id}}/projects/{{Project_Id}}`

**HTTP method:**
`GET`

**Result:**

```
{
   "id": "**************************",
   "account_id": "**************************",
   "name": "My Project(2)",
   "start_date": "2018-11-06",
   "end_date": "2018-12-06",
   "value": null,
   "currency": "USD",
   "status": "active",
   "job_number": null,
   "address_line_1": null,
   "address_line_2": null,
   "city": null,
   "state_or_province": null,
   "postal_code": null,
   "country": "United States",
   "business_unit_id": null,
   "created_at": "2019-01-14T15:31:25.950Z",
   "updated_at": "2019-01-18T09:35:27.071Z",
   "project_type": "Demonstration Project",
   "timezone": null,
   "language": "en",
   "construction_type": null,
   "contract_type": null,
   "last_sign_in": "2019-01-15T14:59:08.000Z",
   "service_types": "doc_manager,insight,admin"
}
```

Also using a `GET` method on the following URL doesn't exist.
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/{{Account_Id}}/projects/{{Project_Id}}/image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we provide the PATCH API to upload/update the image of a BIM360 project, but there is not an API to fetch Project Image, this is already tracked internally, I will add more comments for this request.